# ESXI + pFsense + L3 Switch + Airport extreme setup advice

Tags: switch, wireless, vlan, pfsense

I have been struggling with this issue for a few days now. please bear with me, I am not a expert in networking.

I am trying to setup ESXI lab with network segmentation based on Vlans defined in pfSense and a Cisco SG300 switch in L3 mode to which I also have an Airport extreme BS attached, which will have a private and guest network setup.

A good picture is worth 1000 words, hence I have tried my best to illustrate the design that I have in my mind.

Constraints:

- Airport extreme doesn't have routing features.

Can you please review and advice on how to best realize this setup?

[Highlevel design http://cosni.in/homelab/1.png](http://cosni.in/homelab/1.png)
[Physical connections http://cosni.in/homelab/2.png](http://cosni.in/homelab/2.png)
http://cosni.in/homelab/3.png

I would like to support the following scenarios with this setup.

[Requiremnt 1 http://cosni.in/homelab/4.png](http://cosni.in/homelab/4.png)
[Requirement 2 http://cosni.in/homelab/5.png](http://cosni.in/homelab/5.png)
[Requirement 3 http://cosni.in/homelab/6.png](http://cosni.in/homelab/6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few points regarding the presented configuration and assuming you have shared your complete VLAN footprint regarding the physical and virtual switching.

Any additional information would be helpful.

1. pfSense

   - Configure a public VLAN in the Physical Switch
   - Configure a public virtual switch within the ESXi host
2. Apple Airport Config

   - Configure a VLAN for 172.16.42.0/24
   - Configure a route to pass through the private pfSense interface
   - Validate quad 0 route on pfSense for Internet access
   - Ensure there is only one route for the guest network.  Allowing anonymous users into a the environment, I assume, is against the organizations security policy
   - Configure VLAN in physical switch for 10.0.1.0/24 for the private wireless.  Ensure this VLAN can access resources in other VLAN's for services such as DNS, etc.
3. Network Modem attached to GE10

   - Add appropriate VLAN's to physical switch
   - Ensure GE10 has appropriate routes

Primary questions regarding access revolve around routing.  The Cisco SG-300 has a limited command set and is NOT a full IOS Cisco product.  All of the routing can be done via the https interface of the device.